# MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'

Tags: ibm-mq

When i try to put message into the MQ, I get the following error.

> MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'.

I tried to Google it up. The solution I was able to find is that this issue might arise if the JRE, Eclipse and the MQ are not compatible (Compatible as in 32 and 64 bit).

Thanks in advance for pointing out where the problem could be and any suggestion regarding how to solve it will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you reviewed this technote that includes some information on troubleshooting this?
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs when you've configured your application to connect in BINDINGS mode (rather than CLIENT mode), and the Java MQ classes are unable to find the native library mqjbnd which is required to connect in BINDINGS mode.

BINDINGS uses shared memory to communicate with the queue manager rather than TCP, and requires the mqjbnd library to do this. BINDINGS mode is faster than CLIENT.

CLIENT uses TCP and doesn't require the mqjbnd native library.

To have the mqjbnd library available, your application must be running on the same physical machine as the queue manager. If you're not, you must use CLIENT.

If you're on 7.1+, then the easiest way is to run setmqenv to setup your environment prior to running your application. If you're on 7.0 then you need to do this manually by setting the Java library path - MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH=/path/to/mqinstall/java/lib (or lib64 if you're a 64-bit JVM).