# QJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'

Tags: ibm-mq

Using WebSphere MQ version 7.0.1.6 on Platform: WebSphere MQ for AIX Mode: 64-bit O/S: AIX 6.1.

I try to connect from a simple OS project running on Weblogic 11.g to connect to MQ in "Binding" mode type. I get the following:

> Error occured when connecting to MQ: Exception occured while unregistering resource; QJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'

Steps I found on the [ibm site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508)
are applied without any result.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: this previous stack overflow thread has some possible solutions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318630/mqje001-completion-code-2-reason-2495

Comment: Do you have the queue manager on the same server as Weblogic?

Comment: @OP: A few information could clarify the situation: Do you have module `libmqjbnd.so`? Does its bitness (32/64) match that of the `java` binary? Have you added its location to `java.library.path`? Does command `ldd libmqjbnd.so` report any unresolved dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your comments.
Issue is solved, this link has been helpful:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508